# Why gcc-12.2 doesn't warn conversion from byte pointer to float pointer as a strict aliasing violation?

Tags: c++

https://godbolt.org/z/a8f36qG5j
`-O2 -Wall -fstrict-aliasing`

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
 
int main()
{
    std::uint8_t arr[4] = {0, 0, 0, 65};
    float n = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(arr);
    return n;
}
```

Result:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 8
        ret
```

The compiler reports 0 warning for `uint8_t` `arr`, but reports `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules` for `uint16_t` `arr`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast
[image]

According to the standard, conversions **to** byte pointer is not a violation, but conversions **from** byte pointer should be a violation if two types are not similar.

Comment: Compilers warn on a "best effort" basis. You can't expect to get a warning for every bad thing. Just be happy that you get the warnings you get.

Comment: The C++ standard allows type-punning through pointers to union members. This means that a pointer to one union member can be used to read or modify a different union member without triggering a strict aliasing violation. Because of this, the compiler is not required to issue a warning for this code.